# Is it possible to de-bevel all or parts of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edit-mode

Is there an easy way to un-bevel parts of a mesh that have been beveled?

e.g. Convert this:

[image]

into a normal cube?

### Edit:

Is this possible with perhaps some trick of calculating where the original edge was and collapsing all the selected edges to that point? (python?)

Comment: I get what you are asking but I also don't think it is possible to calculate where the previous edge was just like that. As I said, once you have confirmed it using `Ctrl + B`, it is now permanent. At most, such an algorithm would need the previous shape (mesh coords) etc. Best to use the modifier or make a copy of the object before bevelling.

Comment: This isn't possible currently, we could write some tool to do this, but its fairly involved and not sure its so useful to have?

Comment: @ideasman42 It would be useful, but mainly for compensation of user error (the error being not using the modifier). For now I'm accepting the answer to my question as "This would be possible, but it's not worth the effort"

Comment: @ideasman42 I agree, it would no doubt be a very involved process to go about this and _IMO_ would not be worth the effort as the existing modifier already has the functionality built in to an extent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I didn't use a bevel modifier but I beveled directly the shape edge of the mesh with **Ctrl+b**, I usually use this procedure:

1. In edit mode, set the Pivot to Active element;
2. select all edges I have to de-bevel and for last one I select the one aligned to the original position that I will use as reference;
3. scale the selection to 0 on the needed axis only, to align all beveled edges to the reference edge;
4. repeat the same operation with the other side to de-bevel changing the last selected edge and axis accordingly, as needed;
5. Remove double vertexes.

This works on one "beveled corner" at once and if the edges to be de-beveled are aligned or orthogonal to axis. If they aren't there is the need to set a different xyz ref system to match local edges alignment.

If you wish, see the following video to see the tutorial I made:

http://sendvid.com/5rs3n0uz

Answer (score 4):

Provided your object is aligned to the global axis, this is possible, though somewhat cumbersome:

1. Extrude each end edge and move them so they meet:

   [image]
2. With the extruded vertices selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected*
3. Delete the extruded verts
4. Select the bevel vertices and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Selection to Cursor (Offset)* one by one:
5. <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove Doubles*

   [image]

Some limitations are that it only works for edge bevels, can be tedious for high segment bevels, and is inaccurate when the object is not aligned to the world.

Comment: This answer is very case specific for such a general question.. tedious is also an understatement. As I said in my answer, better to use the modifier. All of this can be reverted in a single click rather than creating an entire new 'de-bevelling' workflow.

Comment: @iKlsR The bevel modifier is without a doubt the better solution, (I am going to use it in the future for sure..) but I still think it is possible to make some python operator to do this.

Comment: @iKlsR - except the question isn't "what bevelling method should I use that allows editing later" it is "How do I remove existing bevels" and the only way to do that is to re-construct the original edge. For the example cube you could re-create the edges, more complex shapes may not be worth the effort. The steps presented are fairly straight forward and could be used as a basis for a python script that could undo a variety of existing bevels.

Comment: @sambler Actually, the specific title is _"Is it possible to de-bevel all or parts of a mesh?"_. It is a general question and I gave a general definitive answer as it relates to Blender _(also noting that one way to go about this would be to manually recreate the original edge(s))_. OP's answer while fine had some pitfalls which I noted [above](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/is-it-possible-to-de-bevel-all-or-parts-of-a-mesh/2735?noredirect=1#comment4623_2735) and in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using the interactive bevel tool

No, this is not possible. Once you have made any changes to the settings in the *Toolshelf* after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and deselected the mesh or completed the operation etc, these changes are now permanent. You can always eyeball it and try to get back the original shape but this can get cumbersome on even simple objects *(and is often not worth the effort)*.

#### Using the modifier

[image]

This is possible to an extent with the *Bevel Modifier* as modifiers allow non-destructive editing and mesh deformation etc. You could create a vertex group of sides that you want to bevel and then just modify or remove as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Though all answers here are correct, I believe the method I just thought about is accurate too. As mentioned in your question, this is some kind of a calculating trick.

1. Select one of the two edges at the end of the bevel and put the cursor to the selection

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>  Cursor to selected

2. Select the opposite edge and seperate it from the cube with

> <kbd>P</kbd> Selection

3. Now switch to object mode and select the separated edge
4. Set the origin of the seperated edge to the 3D cursor (can only be done in object mode)

> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> Origin to 3D Cursor

[image: fig 1]

5. Still in object mode, apply a mirror modifier, in this case, mirrored on the Y-axis. Apply the modifier and go into edit mode.
6. Put the cursor right between the two edges by selecting them and pressing

> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> cursor to selected

Hey! The cursor is right there where you need it, that's the little
calculating
trick:D
[image: fig 2]

7. Now you can go back into object mode and delete the object with the separated and mirrored edges. Select the Cube and go into edit mode, now select one of the two edges at the end of the bevel and put them to the cursor with an offset like so (You have to do this with both of the edges at the end of the bevel individually):

> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Selection to Cursor (Offset)

8. Now you have to delete the edges that are left between the bevel and fill the faces that are deleted through deleting the edges. Don't forget to remove doubles and you're done, the bevel is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this and it works fine; I discovered this when I created a beam with several complex cuts in it, beveled with the modifier, applied and saved and later changed my mind about the bevel. If the bevel is just a matter of a few mm or so, select the part(s) you want to debevel, choose "remove doubles" and change the default value to the distance between the bevel vertices. It will merge the beveled edges at each vertex pair centre. Result..original mesh pre bevel. Just remember next time you use the remove doubles option to change the number back to the default.

Comment: This will *usually* merge the bevel back into one edge, but the edge won't be in the same place as the original edge.