# Manually Un-beveling a corner

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

Decided to try to learn Blender, so started modelling new shelving using it.  Early on I had beveled a corner (not with a modifier) where the shelving goes from one wall to another.  We have since decided we would prefer it sharp.  I understand that the modifier would have been the better choice, but as I beveled with relatively few segments, I thought that it would be a good exercise to learn how one might manually remove the additional segments...so far though, no luck.  Can anyone suggest a course of editing to convert the two sections shown to 90 degree corners?

[image: In need in un-beveling]

Comment: I saw that answer, but it doesn't really answer the question, just suggests not doing what I had done.  After searching, and then posting however, I did find a post with an answer for my question: [Is it possible to de-bevel all or parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/is-it-possible-to-de-bevel-all-or-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: You missed a link, you probably meant [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/is-it-possible-to-de-bevel-all-or-parts-of-a-mesh)